# changing content from list items

Tags: javascript

I have a list of multiple items, a small image frame and with it all a description.

I need to bind a certain image + description to the list items, so if item5 is chosen it's showing one type of picture and description, and so on(all of them would be unique).

I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this since I'm new to js, I did try the basic, setting a class to an item, then in js fetching the class and changing the content.

Here I'm trying to change only the text, but that doesn't seem to be working out either: https://jsfiddle.net/8z37f15j/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="list">
    <ol>
      <li id="item1">items1</li>
      <li>items2</li>
      <li>items3</li>
      <li>items4</li>
      <li>items5</li>
      <li>items6</li>
      <li>items7</li>
      <li>items8</li>
      <li>items9</li>
      <li>items10</li>
      <li>items11</li>
      <li>items12</li>
      <li>items13</li>
      <li>items14</li>
      <li>items15</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="image-container">
    <div id="image">
      <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="description">
        just a placeholder text for when nothing has been chosen.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 /* containers  */
    * {
      font-family: Corbel;
    }

    #wrapper {
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 10px;
      display: inline-flex;
    }

    #image,
    #description,
    #list {
      border: 1px solid #472836;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    /* list  */
    #list {
      width: 150px;
      height: 250px;
      background-color: #9AD2CB;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #list ol {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #list li {
      padding: 5px;
    }

    #list li:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #91f2e6;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #list li:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: red;
    }

    /* sub-container */
    #image,
    #description {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
    }

    #image {
      background-color: #D7EBBA;
    }

    #image img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #description {
      background-color: #FEFFBE;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      height: 95px;
    }
```

**JS:**

```
var desc_area = document.getElementById('description');

var desc1 = "random text for desc1";

function item1(){
    desc_area.innerHTML += desc1;

}
```

Comment: Does the image + description div have unique identifiers (id/class) linked to each list item or are they sorted where the first image + description div is for the first list item, the second div to the second list item and so on?

Comment: @AndrewL I feel like having the image and description be linked to the list item would be more efficient than having them go by order, cause then there's no room for errors and a lot easier to just go in and edit "item1" or "item2" description/img, or maybe its just me.

Comment: That's true yeah. Let me try fiddling around with your jsfiddle.

Comment: @AndrewL Actually, maybe if i do create like an array of the description/img and then do it by order, now thinking it actually might just be better, since you wouldnt need to class each item, which would you more likely go for? I guess linking them would be easier to read, maybe its just a subjective matter

Comment: Both have their own pros and cons but I feel like the best approach would be to create a new div "image-container" for each list item but only the selected list item's div should be displayed. Clicking on another item simply shows the respective div and hide the others. This means less js and more html. It all depends on whether you prefer more js and less html or more html and less js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register each element as a key in a `Map` and create description and the source of an image for that element as a corresponding value (in this case object). I have registered only the first item but others can be done in the same way so right now you can click on the `item1` and see the result.

```js
const desc_area = document.getElementById('description');
const image = document.querySelector('img');
const item1 = document.querySelector('#item1');
const map = new Map();

// register item element as a key and object with corresponding description / image as value
map.set(item1, { desc: 'some description for item1', img: 'url/of/image' });

// you can bind on click handler for example
const list = document.querySelector('ol');
list.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // if element that was registered in our map triggered the event
  if (map.has(event.target)) {
    // change text of description area
    desc_area.textContent = map.get(event.target).desc;
    // change src of the image
    image.src = map.get(event.target).img;
  }
});
```

```css
/* containers  */
   * {
     font-family: Corbel;
   }

   #wrapper {
     border: 1px solid red;
     padding: 10px;
     display: inline-flex;
   }

   #image,
   #description,
   #list {
     border: 1px solid #472836;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 5px;
   }

   /* list  */
   #list {
     width: 150px;
     height: 250px;
     background-color: #9AD2CB;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }

   #list ol {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }

   #list li {
     padding: 5px;
   }

   #list li:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #91f2e6;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

   #list li:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     color: red;
   }

   /* sub-container */
   #image,
   #description {
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
   }

   #image {
     background-color: #D7EBBA;
   }

   #image img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

   #description {
     background-color: #FEFFBE;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     height: 95px;
   }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="list">
        <ol>
          <li id="item1">items1</li>
          <li>items2</li>
          <li>items3</li>
          <li>items4</li>
          <li>items5</li>
          <li>items6</li>
          <li>items7</li>
          <li>items8</li>
          <li>items9</li>
          <li>items10</li>
          <li>items11</li>
          <li>items12</li>
          <li>items13</li>
          <li>items14</li>
          <li>items15</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div id="image-container">
        <div id="image">
          <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="description">
            just a placeholder text for when nothing has been chosen.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you mean and could easily work with data attributes. Just add data attribute of the image path and then grab that and update your image with the data. Something like

```
<li data-imgsrc="/path/to/item2/image" data-desc="Description for the image 2">items2</li>
<li  data-imgsrc="/path/to/item3/image" data-desc="Description for the image3">items3</li>
<li  data-imgsrc="/path/to/item4/image" data-desc="Description for the image4">items4</li>
```

Just make one listener for the `li` elements and grab the imgsrc and the desc and put them in the dom where needed.